# Pycharm doesn't show suggestions of methods of an object inside of an object

Tags: python-3.x

I was watching a tutorial on making a RGB game and I was confused as to why pycharm wouldn't show suggestions in one case.

The case is, I have made objects from a class called "Spell" like this

```
# Create Black Magic
fire = Spell("Fire", 10, 100, "black")
thunder = Spell("Thunder", 10, 100, "black")
blizzard = Spell("Blizzard", 10, 100, "black")
meteor = Spell("Meteor", 20, 200, "black")
quake = Spell("Quake", 14, 140, "black")

# Create White Magic
cure = Spell("Fire", 12, 120, "white")
cura = Spell("Cure", 18, 200, "white")
```

Then with these objects, I put them as one of the attributes of another object("player") of a different class(Character)

```
player = Character(460, 70, 80, 50, [fire, thunder, blizzard, meteor, quake, cure, cura])
enemy = Character(1200, 65, 45, 25, [])
```

Then I get user to select the magic

```
magic_choice = int(input("Choose your magic")) - 1

magic_dmg = player.magic[magic_choice].generate_damage()
```

But when I try to write

```
magic_dmg = player.magic[magic_choice].generate_damage()
```

Pycharm cannot find ".generate_damage()" method which is stored in a different file. The code works but it can't give suggestions. What could be the reasons for this?

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, hp, mp, atk, df, magic):
        self.max_hp = hp
        self.hp = hp
        self.max_mp = mp
        self.mp = mp
        self.atk_l = atk - 10
        self.atk_h = atk + 10
        self.df = df
        self.magic = magic


class Spell:   
    def __init__(self, name, cost, dmg, type):
        self.name = name
        self.cost = cost
        self.dmg = dmg
        self.type = type

    def generate_damage(self):
        mag_l = self.dmg - 15
        mag_h = self.dmg + 15
        return random.randrange(mag_l, mag_h)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said what type `self.magic`, so there's no possible way that it could know that it's a list of `Spell`s.

You need to an annotate the attribute using [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

```
from typing import List

. . . 

# magic is a list of spells
self.magic: List[Spell] = magic
```

Comment: I actually did spell = player.magic[magic_choice] and wrote spell.generate_damage() and the suggestions were seen at "spell." But if I just used "player.magic[magic_choice]."  no suggestions were seen though they are the same.